# How to change label tick color in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a seaborn plot and I would like to create custom tick label coloring for it.

The code is:

```
short_cols = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6', 'col_7', 'col_8', 'col_9', 'col_10', 'col_11', 'col_12', 'col_13', 'col_14', 'col_15', 'col_16', 'col_17', 'col_18', 'col_19']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,10)) 
sns.heatmap(jr_matrix, 
            center=0, 
            cmap="vlag", 
            linewidths=.75, 
            ax=ax,
            norm=LogNorm(vmin=jr_matrix.min(), vmax=jr_matrix.max()))
ax.set_xticklabels(short_cols, rotation=90, size=14, labelcolor='red')
ax.set_yticklabels(short_cols, rotation=0, size=14)
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

There is a certain grouping between some of the items in short_cols such that it would be useful to be able set them to the same color.

My question is, how can I adjust the ticklabel colors so that I can reflect this association in the plot.

For example, lets say the groups are:

```
group1 = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']
group2 = ['col_4', 'col_5']
group3 = ['col_6']
...
group7=['col_18', 'col_19']
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: `for tick, color in zip(ax.get_ticklabels(), colors): tick.set_color(color)`?

Comment: looks pretty close, trying to make it work...

Comment: That is basically correct.  Had to modify it to change `ax.get_ticklabels()` to `ax.get_xticklabels()` and then it worked.

Answer (score 5):

```
confusion_M  = pd.crosstab(model1_pred.Predicted_class,model1_pred.Actual_class)
sn.set(rc={'axes.facecolor':'black', 'figure.facecolor':'black',})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,10))
g= sn.heatmap(confusion_M,annot=True,cmap = "coolwarm",fmt = ".1f",annot_kws= 
{'size':100})
for tick_label in g.axes.get_yticklabels():
    tick_label.set_color("white")
    tick_label.set_fontsize("30")
fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.